# "Typo" is a meta tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, a user created the [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) tag and added it to [an old question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/4850/revisions) that had been closed as Too Localized because it asked about a typo.  I decided to roll this change back and remove the tag.

It seems like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me:

> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

I don't think [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) would ever work as a tag on its own.  No one would ever want to look through the list of [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) questions (presumably all closed), nor would anyone want to follow questions tagged [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo).  What's more, new questions would never be tagged this way because no one would ask a [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) question on purpose, and seeing "typo - Did the author forget to use 'if' or I'm missing some literary style" on Google would just be strange.

(We had this problem on Japanese.SE and ended up burninating the tag.)

I don't think we should add [typo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo) to questions on ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that "typo" is not a worthwhile tag. I have a difficult time being organized (at least in a way that other folks can perceive) and it took me a long time to understand that just because every item is labelled or categorized doesn't necessarily mean the items are organized. A "typo" tag adds nothing to the organization of the answers. Typos are by their nature inconsistent, so the tag would label the item without adding any real information about it.

It is better for tags to be too general than too specific, in my opinion, particularly when non-native speakers are the audience. I think "tense" is a good tag. English learners far enough along to ask a question here and understand the answer probably understand when "tense" is important to their question. I think "past-perfect-tense" would not be a good tag, because it doesn't make an answer that much easier to find than "tense", but it could cause some answers to be missed in a search if the searcher didn't know what verb tense they were dealing with and the item wasn't also labelled "tense".